# Microsoft Word VBA tab key to make textbox visible

Tags: vba, ms-word, textbox

Longtime viewer, first time question asker.

I'm currently working with UserForms within MS Word and have a particular form that can have up to 20 different labels and accompanying textboxes with varying texts.  I have all but the first hidden while not in use, however I would like the next label and text box to become visible following input in the previous textbox.  So if you enter data (anything) in the first textbox, the next label and text box will become visible.  Does this make sense? I've seen other responses here suggest using AfterUpdate() rather than Change() or Click() but can't figure out how to use any of them. I would share my code but at this point I don't have any code to share, other than my labels and textboxes are lblField1 txtField1, lblField2 txtField2...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you searched for making controls visible to get a starting point?  There is likely basic code out there.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `Change event`, when using `AfterUpdate` you need to leave you `TextBox` for a while to fire the event. If you have only one `TextBox` visible there is nothing to move to. If you have more `TextBoxes` you would need to move back to fire `AfterEvent` and I don't think this is what you expect.

So, double click wherever on your userform and add the following code in code area:

```
Private Sub txtField1_Change()
    txtField2.Visible = True
    lblField2.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Next, add next portion for next textbox:

```
Private Sub txtField2_Change()
    txtField3.Visible = True
    lblField3.Visible = True
End Sub
```

And so on, if only you have an order in controls name you just need to change numbers in the end of control names.